# Get parent header from selected child

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

This is my first post. Please forgive me if i write something that doesn't fit in.

I'm using a treeview and want to get the header of a parent from a selected child when i doubleclick the child. Everything is done in the code behind. Something like this:

```
Parent1
   ---> Child1
   ---> Child2
Parent2
   ---> Child3
   ---> Child4
```

When i doubleclick Child1, i want the header of Parent1. Is this possible in some how?

Comment: Are you using winform or asp?

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework 4 if this helps

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```
private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView tv = (TreeView)sender;

        TreeViewItem child = (TreeViewItem)tv.SelectedItem;
        if (child.Parent.GetType() == typeof(TreeViewItem)) // verify that parent is TreeViewItem
        {
            TreeViewItem parent =(TreeViewItem)child.Parent; 
            string text = parent.Header.ToString();
        }

    }
```

```xml
<TreeView Height="92" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="treeView1"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MouseDoubleClick="treeView1_MouseDoubleClick">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Header1">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Child1" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Child2" />
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Header2">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Child3" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Child4" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I would use `if(child.Parent is TreeViewItem)` instead of GetType(), since GetType() _Gets the Type of the current instance. (Inherited from Object.)_

Answer (score 0):

Give your TreeView a name. You could use element binding in your child like this:

```
{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=Header}
```

Or you can find the parent like this:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type namespace:TreeView}}, Path=Header, Mode=TwoWay}
```